# multiple selector jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i've got this ugly jquery selectors..

```
$('div img').eq(3).css('padding-right', '0'); //multiple of 4...
$('div img').eq(7).css('padding-right', '0');
$('div img').eq(11).css('padding-right', '0');
$('div img').eq(15).css('padding-right', '0');
```

i have to get all imgages in  positioned in 4^ and multiple-of-4 positions...

is there a better code than mine? :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes:

```
$('div img:nth-child(4n+3)').css('padding-right', '0');
```

Comment: Very nice! +1! (SO won't allow comments with length <15)

Answer (score 1):

You can use nth-child as illustrated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/YdsjY/